# How do I add and delete products displayed in a block on my homepage? My site runs on Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2

[image: Screenshot showing specified block]

I know the location of the Block but what I don't  know yet is how to add and delete the products displayed on the block.
Thank you

Comment: you are using `codazon fastest` theme ?

Comment: Yes, I use codazon fastest theme.

Comment: if you look code of static block they added widget for products. in widget theme using category id.you need to change category id.

Comment: Thank you. Would I find the settings in Admin Portal/Content/widgets or in Admin Portal/Content/blocks?

Comment: You need to edit `Content/blocks`.

Comment: could you add block code here ?

Comment: Thank you I followed your answer and it worked, I just changed the category Id. At first I had challenge locating where the category id was but I later found it. Solved!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to know @Austin. I have put my comment as an answer. You can up-vote and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `codazon fastest` theme.

if you look code of static block they added widget for products. In widget, theme using `category id`.

**You need to change category id.**

You can edit id from `Content/blocks`.

Comment: The widget is not displayed after upgrading magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.4, any idea ?